# $ being interpreted as Latex in "Hot Network Questions" from Latex enabled sites

Tags: bug

an image is better than a thousand words:

[image]

Original title:

[Should I get $200 for passing "Go" if I then get a card that says "don't collect $200"?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32485/should-i-get-200-for-passing-go-if-i-then-get-a-card-that-says-dont-collect)